# How to fix or correct a BST by swapping the nodes in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, swap

I have an incorrect BST where two nodes are not in the right position. I know that inorder traversal of a BST is sorted. Hence I traverse through the tree with three pointers : first, last, middle. If the current node is less than previous node, I set previous node as first and current node as middle. This is for the first violation. When second violation occurs, I assign last as current node. Now when last is `NULL`, swap first and middle and when last is not `NULL` swap first and last. This is what I have done:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,data):
      self.data = data
      self.left = None
      self.right = None


def fixBST(root,first,middle,last,prev):

    if( root ): 


        fixBST( root.left, first, middle, last, prev )

        if (prev and root.data < prev.data): 

            if ( first is None ): 

                first = prev 
                middle = root 

            else:
                last = root


        prev = root


        fixBST( root.right, first, middle, last, prev )
        return (first,middle,last)


def correctBST( root ): 


    first = middle = last = prev = None 


    first,middle,last = fixBST( root, first, middle, last, prev ) 

    if( first and last ): 
              t = first.data 
              first.data = last.data 
              last.data = t 
    elif( first and middle ): 
              t = first.data 
              first.data = middle.data 
              middle.data = t 



def printInorder(node): 

    if (node == None): 
        return
    printInorder(node.left)
    print node.data
    printInorder(node.right) 



root = Node(6)
root.left     = Node(10) 
root.right     = Node(2) 
root.left.left = Node(1) 
#root.left.right = Node(3) 
#root.right.right = Node(12) 
#root.right.left = Node(7) 

print "Inorder Traversal of the original tree \n" 
printInorder(root)

correctBST(root)

print "\nInorder Traversal of the fixed tree \n"
printInorder(root)
```

I get the same incorrect tree after printing inorder traversal the second time. I believe the first, middle, last values are not getting stored? Am I missing out on something?

EDIT: I edited the code. But still the return value of first, middle and last is None. Is it not the right way?

Comment: To clarify: the input is a tree that can be turned into a BST by swapping exactly one pair of values?

Comment: Yes, two nodes will be out of place and when we swap them, the tree will be a proper BST.

Answer (score 0):

You functions `fixBST` and `swap` don't **do** anything. `first`, `middle`, and `last` are confined to the local scope of the `fixBST`, so yes in this sense they are not *stored*. [Python passes by assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

```
def swap(a,b): 

    t = a 
    a = b 
    b = t 

a, b = 1, 2
swap(a, b)
print(a, b)
# 1 2
```

What you should do is either return a value and reassign or use global scope:

```
# Reassign
def swap(a,b): 
    return b, a

a, b = 1, 2
a, b = swap(a, b)
print(a, b)
# 2 1

# Global
a, b = 1, 2
def swap():
    global a
    global b
    t = a
    a = b
    b = t
swap()
print(a, b)
# 2 1
```

Probably reassign is the way to go.

Comment: I edited the code but still the values of first, last and middle are returned as None.